# Why is `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config` taken into account only when the fork count is equal to zero during the tests?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, easymock, cglib, java-16

I use Maven 3.8.1 and Maven surefire plugin 3.0.0-M5 with OpenJDK 16. `.mvn/jvm.config` contains `--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` in order to fix the following error:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make
> protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @319aa9ee

Why do I need to pass `-DforkCount=0` to Maven to make it work? `.mvn/jvm.config` seems to be ignored when I run `mvn install` alone without forcing the unforked VM. Is there a cleaner solution?

You can reproduce my problem by using the following project:
https://jogamp.org/cgit/ardor3d.git/

P.S: The problem is caused by EasyMock 4.3. It uses Objenesis under the hood which claims to support Java 16, it's supported with some tweaks, [it's a known concern](https://github.com/easymock/objenesis/issues/70#issuecomment-791980297). sun.misc.Unsafe is mentioned but not the method above.

P.S 2: A stack trace mentions cglib [which doesn't support Java 17 yet](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/issues/191):

> Caused by: org.easymock.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException:
> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make
> protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @2064d52f

Reference:
https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options

Comment: This is not possible, the `jvm.config` solely applies to Maven and not forked JVM which run tests independency of Maven's classpath.

Comment: @Michael-O Thank you, I'll try to get rid of jvm.config but I haven't found any way of making EasyMock work without it for now.